# Redirecting /directory/index.html to /directory/

Tags: mod-rewrite, redirect, apache

Hey guys I'm not sure how to phrase this to get the correct search, so here goes
i would like to redirect all queries for /directory/index.html to /directory/
which is (really) /directory/index.php I wrote this out but it inserts my entire
web root structure (/var/www/html/directory/index.php) so it's a no go, maybe
someone could help me a bit? Does this make sense?

here's the code

> RewriteEngine On
>
> RewriteRule ^index.(htm|html?)$ ^index.php [R=301,L]

**EDIT**

I solved it with this, but I'm sure theres a better way?

> RewriteEngine On
>
> RewriteRule ^index.(htm|html?)$ %{REQUEST_URI}/../index.php [R=301,L]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might work (and is cleaner, I think):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^index\.(htm|html?)$ /index.php [QSA,NC,R=301,L]
```